# awk and passing variables into regexp: root canal of var assignment

Tags: regex, awk

I have searched high and low and cannot find a simple, cohesive, medium level explanation of how to do the following:

```
awk -v var="CHEM" '/var/' file1
```

How can I pass one measly variable directly into a regexp? Apparently it defies description for the mortal human learning `awk`, or is so intuitive a simpleton like me should refrain from asking.

The reason is I am "trying" to write a script (without having an aneurysm) that will cycle a list of variables into a regexp and take out chunks of text. This inability for me to pass variables (I've tried `~`, other things to no avail) is a major roadblock for what is otherwise getting to be a done deal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -v var="CHEM" '$0 ~ var { print }' file1
```

Use an explicit match operation and do not mask the variable in the regular expression `/…/` notation.  The `{ print }` is optional; if you omit it, the print will be done as the default action (and plain `print` is equivalent to `print $0` — print the input line).